# Node.js - Discord Hug Command - User specific not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I've scowered Google to try and find a solution but nothing has warranted any results.

I'm not sure why the code below isn't returning "User hugs User".

No error codes on the terminal.

Code below;

```
 if (words == `${prefix}hug`) {
   return message.channel.send(`${message.author} sends love to ${message.mentions.users.first()} with a hug!`);
  
}
 if (!message.mentions.users.first()) return message.reply("You need to mention someone to hug them");
```

Comment: Use \`\`\` when code starts and ends to create a code block. ```like this```

Comment: Hi both, many thanks for your replies. I've tried both of these methods and neither has worked sadly. "words ==" isn't defined so I've changed it to "command" and the user still isn't specified. I directly copied and pasted the edit you gave me @phix. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. Many thanks again,

Comment: I didn't do anything besides edit your post. You said "User hugs User" but that text isn't in your post. Please edit with more information, it's unclear how that string is occurring.